# How to count the matches between two files in python?

Tags: python

i'm new using python and the question is that i dont know where i can start to solve the following issue

i have 3 files

1 file contains something like that :

```
pm_rpm@fences
pm_rpm@fences-dpms
pm_rpm@modeset-lpsp-stress
pm_rpm@modeset-non-lpsp-stress
pm_rpm@modeset-lpsp-stress-no-wait
pm_rpm@modeset-non-lpsp-stress-no-wait
pm_rpm@modeset-pc8-residency-stress
pm_rpm@modeset-stress-extra-wait
pm_rpm@system-suspend
pm_rpm@system-suspend-execbuf
pm_rpm@system-suspend-modeset
```

this 1 file contain all the tests that i will run

the second file looks like this :

```
kms_vblank@accuracy
kms_vblank@query-idle
kms_vblank@query-busy
kms_vblank
```

the third file looks like this :

```
kms_flip@2x-rcs-wf_vblank-vs-modeset
kms_flip@basic-plain-flip
kms_flip@2x-plain-flip
kms_flip@busy-flip
kms_flip@2x-busy-flip
```

so basically i need to check how many tests in file 2 and file 3 are in the file 1, and get something output like this

```
file 2 : 3 tests found
file 3 : 10 tests found
```

but for example if in any of file 2 or file 3 i have a test with wildcard like this :

gem_concurrent*

i will need that the python script works with wildcards as well

thanks so much for your help on this

Comment: So in short, need to find the tests common in (file 1 and 2 ) and (file 1 and 3) ? How big the files can be? Is performance an issue?

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have and where y I u think it goes wrong.

Comment: for the momment i dont have any code, the file one can has more less 70000 lines and file 2 can has more less 1500 lines and file 3 can has 2000 lines, and yes i need to find the tests common  in (file 1 and 2 ) and (file 1 and 3)

Comment: Do the test names include the characters before the '@' symbol, or just the ones after it?

Comment: Please don't tag questions with `[python-2.7]` and `[python-3.x]` unless you have a question about a difference between the two versions. Here, and for most questions, a simple `[python]` will suffice. Also, this question has nothing to do with Linux.

Comment: Before the "@" mean the family test and after "@" mean subtests

Comment: You need to start by coming up with a very thorough, precise definition of your "test" language (if one doesn't already exist). For the life of me, I have no idea where those 3 and 10 numbers come from. Then you need create a parser for the "test" language (if one doesn't already exist) and write code that is able to parse the files. *Then* you can start thinking about how to do the comparison.

Comment: Can you post some file hosting link with sample files and output so I can test my answer?

Comment: @Wajahat That's a horrible way of testing an answer. You need the full language specification, not just a sample.

Comment: It is just counting common lines between files, should be a simple python script

Comment: @Wajahat Then the answers would be 0. None of the prefixes match. On top of that, "accuracy," "idle," and "busy" don't even show up in the first file, yet the OP claims that the file containing them has 3 matches with the first file! This is nowhere near simple string matching. What are you talking about?

Comment: Oh no, I mean he obviously posted just the top lines in each file. That is why I am asking for the whole sample.

Comment: @Wajahat That is not obvious at all.

Comment: Well I did confirm from him that the problem is to just find common lines in two pairs of files, (1,2),(1,3) with support for wild card characters (regex)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113687/discussion-between-jpmc26-and-wajahat).

Comment: This is a normal counting problem, just instead of counting inside the same file you count between them. Just split your files into lists by lines, either by using readlines() when reading them or by .split("\n")ting them afterwards, then loop overfirst and inside it have two loops, one for count in second, and one to count in third file. Use dict or dicts to count. Do you need to know which file has what? If you don't you can merge all data together and just count occurrences. To use wildcards, you will have to use regular expressions or implement your own mechanism to recognize similarities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written these programs using python 3, the fist only includes the tests after the '@' symbol, the second includes the whole test name:

```
file1=open("file1.txt")
file2=open("file2.txt")
file3=open("file3.txt")
f1=file1.read().split("\n")
f2=file2.read().split("\n")
f3=file3.read().split("\n")
file1.close()
file2.close()
file3.close()

f1s,f2s,f3s=[],[],[]        #file1 split, file2 split, file3 split
try: [f1s.append(i.split("@")[1]) for i in f1]
except IndexError: pass

try: [f2s.append(i.split("@")[1]) for i in f2]
except IndexError: pass

try: [f3s.append(i.split("@")[1]) for i in f3]
except IndexError: pass

match2=0
for i in f2s:
    if i[-1:]=="*":
        i=i[:-1]
        if [e for e in f1s if e[:len(i)]==i]: match2+=1
    elif i in f1s: match2+=1

match3=0
for i in f3s:
    if i[-1:]=="*":
        i=i[:-1]
        if [e for e in f1s if e[:len(i)]==i]: match3+=1
    elif i in f1s: match3+=1

print("file 2:", match2, "tests found")
print("file 3:", match3, "tests found")
```

Second program:

```
f1=open("file1.txt")
f2=open("file2.txt")
f3=open("file3.txt")
f1s=f1.read().split("\n")
f2s=f2.read().split("\n")
f3s=f3.read().split("\n")
f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()

match2=0
for i in f2s:
    if i[-1:]=="*":
        i=i[:-1]
        if [e for e in f1s if e[:len(i)]==i]: match2+=1
    elif i in f1s:
        match2+=1
match3=0
for i in f3s:
    if i[-1:]=="*":
        i=i[:-1]
        if [e for e in f1s if e[:len(i)]==i]: match3+=1
    elif i in f1s:
        match3+=1
print("file 2:", match2)
print("file 3:", match3)
```

Through the tests I have done, they both seem to work and support wildcards as well, but comment if there is a problem with either.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very dumb solution to do this using python2.7:

```
import re

def findCommon(a,b):
    allmatches=[]
    for test in b:
        if "*" in test or "?" in test:
            reg=re.compile(test)
            matches=[line for line in a for m in [reg.search(line)] if m]
        else:
            matches=[line for line in a if test==line]
        allmatches.extend(matches)
    c=set(allmatches)
    return len(c)

def main():
    content1=[]
    content2=[]
    content3=[]
    with open('file1.txt','r') as f1:
        content1=[line.strip() for line in f1]
    with open('file2.txt','r') as f2:
        content2=[line.strip() for line in f2]
    with open('file3.txt','r') as f3:
        content3=[line.strip() for line in f3]

    print "file 2 :", findCommon(content1,content2),"tests found"
    print "file 3 :", findCommon(content1,content3),"tests found"

main()
```

It first reads the entire files into three lists, and then calls `findCommon` function on two pairs.

`findCommon` function iterates over the 2nd list (file) and checks if the test-name contains a wildcard (of-course this assumes there are only two wildcards; ? and *, which might be wrong). If it does, it uses regex matching on first file otherwise uses simple equality to find matches.
`set` was used to remove duplicate matches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i'll try and i let you know my results